# Form logic questions (use REL or hidden input?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am putting together a form that will receive the telephone number of someone and store it in a database.

I have a *country* select and an input where they type their phone number.

When the user selects their country, I would like to append their country dialing code to the front of their phone number automatically. What is the best approach at doing something like this?

I was thinking: 
A) In the country select, add a rel to each country select. For example, `rel="+1"` for USA, `rel="+33"` for France.
Would it be difficult for our .NET programmer to pull that information out of the select input to use?

or 
B) Add another select and set it to hidden, and bind the country select to the country code select so that the value changes when country is changed.

Do either of these sound like a good option or is there maybe some other means much more "enlightened" than what I have come up with?

Comment: Good idea, but instead of "rel" it might be better to use an HTML5 "data" attribute, like maybe "data-dialing-prefix".

Comment: Hmmm awesome idea! I think its time I pick up an HTML 5 book. I will look into this attribute now. Can you tell me, as a programmer, would it be hard now for you to use that attribute on the backend?

Comment: I guess meaning that you would be able to append the value of "data-dialing-prefix" to the users phone number when entering it into the database?  The reason I ask is because our .NET programmer is a real stickler, always says i am giving her things she cannot work with...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard at all. You don't need to bind any `data` or `rel` attributes at all, you can just use the `value` attribute of `option`s:

```
<select name="country_code">
  <option value="+1">US (+1)</option>
  <option value="+33">France (+33)</option>
</select>
<input name="phone_number" type="text" ...>
```

Then you can just get the full phone number on the server side by pasting together the country code and phone number. You can then check on the server side and see if the user also entered the country code into the phone field, and if so, remove it.

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately the value attribute is already being used by country abbreviations US, CA, etc...